# Modify cout to delay screen output?

Tags: c++

I want to modify cout so that the text is displayed with, say, a 30ms delay between the printing of each character... I can't imagine I am the first person to want to do this using cout, but I also can't find any example of the same.

To be clear, I want to override the stream insertion operator (not overload).

I have already written my own output functions, I want to see if it is possible to modify the standard behavior for an entire solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your requirements? Are you sending a whole text to cout and expect it to print the letters with delay?

Comment: Just create a function which you would use instead of cout. Inside that function, parse the text and put them into cout accordingly

Comment: Using the existing facilities instead of rolling my own console out is the reason I am asking.

Comment: std::cout is constant. Can't be changed. Why don't you just create a function and print in that function?

Comment: Cool, put that as an answer (texasbruce) and I will accept.

Comment: You can change `cout`'s behavior by replacing its streambuf.

Comment: Ahah... put a more detailed answer (links to examples or tutorials) and I will accept that answer, aschepler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do something like:

```
class MyDelayStream
{
public:
    MyDelayStream(std::ostream& os) : os(os) {}

    template <typename T>
    MyDelayStream& operator <<(const T& t)
    {
        using namespace std::literals;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << t;
        for (auto c : ss.str()) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(30ms);
            os << c;
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::ostream& os;
};
```

And then use it like:

```
MyDelayStream s(std::cout);

s << "hello" << 42 << '\n';
```

The hard (missing) part is manipulator and function as `std::endl`.

Comment: Might include a note about how weird doing this is... I am just having fun with a homework assignment that is way too easy.

Comment: You may try by yourself first. I will maybe add more info tomorrow.

Comment: Oh this is great, I just meant I would never ever do this at work... Messing with my professor, on the other hand, is totally fair game.

Comment: How can make it asynchronous with program?